# wordpress post content duplicate

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I've made a home page with four different categories to be shown.I think it was working well, but for now the all posts have the same content as the first post. Links, and featured images, are good, but text somehow is being overwritte.

Heress the screen all texts are the same:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/713/m1j6.jpg

Edited: so this works with `<?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>` inside loops

My code:

```
   <div class="bmw">
     <h2>bmw news</h2>
        <?php $k = 1;  
      $posts = get_posts('category=7&orderby=date&numberposts=2'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
     <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
  <div id="home_post<?php if($k%2 == 0) echo "last" ;?>">

   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div id="img">
     <span>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
       </span>
   </div>
       </a>
    <?php }; ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
    <span id="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></span>
     <?php the_content('...'); ?>
         <div class="button_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Czytaj więcej<span><img style="vertical-align:middle;width:auto;margin-left:5%" src="http://test.startujac.pl/images/strzalka_czytaj_wiecej.png"></span></a></div>
     </div>
    <?php $k++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

<div class="news">
     <h2>VW news</h2>
     <?php $v = 1; 
       $posts = get_posts('category=12&orderby=date&numberposts=2'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
      <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
      <div id="home_post<?php if($v%2 == 0) echo "last" ;?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div id="img">
     <span>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
     </span>
     </div></a>
      <?php } ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
    <span id="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></span>
     <?php the_content('...'); ?>
        <div class="button_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Czytaj więcej<span><img style="vertical-align:middle;width:auto;margin-left:5%" src="http://test.startujac.pl/images/strzalka_czytaj_wiecej.png"></span></a></div>
     </div>
    <?php $v++; ?>
      <?php }?>
     </div>
<div class="japan">
    <h2>japan news</h2>
      <?php $k = 1; 
        $posts = get_posts('category=13&orderby=date&numberposts=2'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
         <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
       <div id="home_post<?php if($k%2 == 0) echo "last" ;?>">
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div id="img">
      <span>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
     </span>
     </div></a>
     <?php } ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
      <span id="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></span>
         <?php the_content('...'); ?>
       <div class="button_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Czytaj więcej<span><img style="vertical-align:middle;width:auto;margin-left:5%" src="http://test.startujac.pl/images/strzalka_czytaj_wiecej.png"></span></a></div>
     </div>
     <?php $k++; ?>
      <?php }  ?>
     </div>



      <div class="events">
       <h2>imprezy i zloty</h2>
        <?php $k = 1; 
      $posts = get_posts('category=1&orderby=date&numberposts=4'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
      <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div id="home_post<?php if($k == 1) echo "first" ;?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
     <div id="img">
      <span>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
     </span>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
       <div id="content">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
     <span id="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></span>
     <?php the_content('...'); ?>
       </div>
       </div>
     <?php $k++; ?>
       <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting `the_post();` on the beginning of your template file? This solves sometimes this kind of problems.

Comment: No i didnt, but what do u mean, exactly ;) ? i got this code in index.php file. So where shud i put that ? above `<?php` or under ?

Comment: You need to put it in the PHP tags like this: `<?php the_post();`.

Comment: but in this file which contains the code i provided above, right ? or other template file ? I added this , but nothing changed.

Comment: Okay, then probably some thing different is going on. You could try adding `<?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>` inside your foreach loops. That's how it works according to the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts)

Comment: Hey man, thanks ! that worked , damn i guess i need to read more wordpress stuff ;)